# Using Auth function in script tag (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel

guys, I am trying to use the `Auth` function in my `script` tag which is inside a `blade` file but it seems like I am getting a yellow warning when I checked their source in google. Is it possible to use the `Auth` function in a script tag or is there an alternative approach for this? Anyone able to help? thanks in advance.

Here my snippets of code in the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('button').click(function(){
        //CONST DATA
        const prefix = "QATS";
        const url = "http://qr5.dev.ificonsultancy.net/api/sendData";

        //Extract Data
        var lecturer_id = Auth::user()->id;     //HERE IS THE ERROR
        var faculty_code = $( "#Faculty" ).val();
        var programme_code = $( "#Programme" ).val();
        var class_code = $("#Class").val();

        //Location Coordinates
        var gps_school_lng =  "101.5597904";
        var gps_school_lat =  "3.0923526";

        //URL Concatenation
        var urlContent = prefix.concat("|",url,"|",lecturer_id,"|",faculty_code,"|",programme_code,"|",class_code,"|",gps_school_lat,"|",gps_school_lng);

        //Add src to #qrImg
        $("img#qrImg").attr('src',"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="+urlContent+"&choe=UTF-8");
        console.log("pass");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use the mustache syntax:

```
var lecturer_id = '{{ Auth::user()->id; }}'
```

Comment: is the semicolon supposed to be inside the brackets or outside?

Comment: Inside. It's normal php within them.

Comment: unfortunately i'm getting an error `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'` any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe try without the semicolon? It's been a long time since used blade templates.

Comment: aw man... now there is a different error `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Comment: Are you signed in? That code will work if so. `auth()->id()` would work too.